# how to create 1px X 1px on .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, jpeg

I need an image 1px X 1px or empty Jpeg image using c#

Comment: Why using C#? Can't you just create one using your favorite image editor?

Comment: No I  need it dynamically restored after (modifying on it and store it with another path)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't test this right now, but shouldn't this work?

```
(new Bitmap(1,1)).Save(name,ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this ..

```
            var image = new Bitmap(1, 1);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            stream.Position = 0;
```

And then save the stream to a file.

Hope this helps.